# How do I set session or global attribute using Spring 3 MVC Annotations

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have a simple application written in Java using Spring MVC. The Credentials class just contains the username & password, supplied at login.

Ideally I want the persons username and full name to be present on every jsp page. I am thinking of setting a session attribute.

My Controller Class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/menu", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addContact(Map<String, Object> map,@ModelAttribute("user")
    User user, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status,HttpSession session) {


session.setAttribute("DisplyName", u.getDisplayName());
```

My JSP:

```
 <div class="wlctxt">Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("DisplyName") %></div>
```

But I get null value of session attribute here.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: did you mean `user.getDisplayName()`

Comment: Did you check that calling getDisplayName() does not return null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put in session attribute DisplayName. You do it with every request. You have model attribute it will be putted in request so in jsp you can access it:

```
<div class="wlctxt">Welcome <c:out value="${user.displayName}"/></div>
```

Putting in session have a lot trobelshouting you have to care about. What if your user change display name? You should update in in session. Or more critical: changing of some access rights? It is easy to foget update in session in every possible places.

I put in session userId by what I can get it from in memory cache (reading from DB expansibe from performance point of view) and do next:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(...)
    public String getSomePage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
        Long userId = (Long) session.getAtribute("currentUserId");
        User user = userService.get(userId);
        request.setAttribute("currentUser", user);
    }
```

In jsp you can access it:

```
<div>Wellcome <c:out value="${currentUser.displayName}"/>!</div>
```